# AppEngine SNI https and Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, chrome-web-store

I am trying to include a https url hosted on AppEngine (with SNI) in a Chrome WebStore manifest.

When I try to to upload the .zip file, the Chrome Webstore complains, that I do not own the url.

So tried to add the url with WebMaster Tools. I am able to add the http url, but cannot verify the https url (It complains about not beeing able to reach the server. I am able to reach the https url from my browser without problems.)

Same problem with the Google Gadget Ownership Verification Tool (https://www.google.com/gadgets/directory/verify), which cannot find (and therefore verify) Appengine SNI https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Many types of Google fetches are not currently sending SNI detail in their SSL handshakes and fail to talk to the service.

I've organised for the feature to be re-enabled and it will be rolled out in coming days.

Comment: I believe WebMaster tools are working now, but the Gadget Ownership Verification Tool is not.

I'll follow up on that.